# Can there be old radio waves broadcasted years ago still traveling in the air?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation

I was studying this radio receiver circuit
[image]
Then I read that radio waves broadcasted by radio stations will keep traveling in the air forever unless absorbed by something and that radio waves can penetrate most things. I wonder that if, some radio waves broadcasted some years ago are not absorbed by anything till now, can they still be traveling in the air now and like, be picked up by this radio circuit and we hear old broadcasted waves now?

Comment: Today while driving out in the middle of no where in the mountains...the station was on but said no reception. Out of nowhere a 1950s Mr clean commercial was playing and some lady started talking then it stopped to nothing. Then after a few seconds of nothing, jailhouse rock was playing. Then nothing .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In air radiowaves will eventually dissipate. The waves that escaped into space however are still speeding away from us, for ever. Much like the sunlight from the day the the dinosaurs were wiped out by an asteroid.

Comment: Why do they dissipate in the air?

Comment: And if they do so, how do they reach the receiver circuit anyways?

Comment: Just like you dissipate energy when walking in loose sand, radiowaves lose energy to the molecules in air. They also lose their coherence. So after seconds a radiowave is completely dissipated. However that is enough to be able to reach a receiver.

Answer (score 10):

the radio waves that this particular radio was designed to receive are prevented from escaping into space by the ionosphere, and hence bounce around between the earth and the underside of the ionosphere. Each bounce dissipates some of the energy of the radio wave, to the extent that after the 3rd or 4th bounce, the radio wave's strength is less than that of the background noise at that frequency and the signal disappears into the noise. This is true even for extremely powerful transmitted signals.

This means you cannot today pick up old radio broadcasts from the past.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder that if, some radio waves broadcasted some years ago are not
> absorbed by anything till now, can they still be traveling in the air
> now

[Radio waves emitted by some celestial objects](https://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Space_Science/Observations_Seeing_in_radio_wavelengths#:%7E:text=The%20collapsed%20hearts%20of%20dead,rotation%20then%20sweeps%20through%20space.) many years ago are being received now by radio telescopes.